# The difference between quell and subdue

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

to quell means:

to stop something that you do not want to happen

to subdue means:

to start to control someone or something, especially by using force

source : cambridge dictionaries

Comment: Those two definitions seem to cover it fairly well - did you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *quell* a bank robber, you *subdue* a bank robber.

When applied to individuals, the word *quell* is often used with emotions: we quell our fears, we quell our urges, we quell our anger.

When applied to groups, we quell rebellions, insurrections, and revolts. [Have a look.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+quelled+the+*&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Of course, the two words are roughly synonymous, so there is plenty of room for overlap. We *can* subdue our anger, for example.

Comment: So can we say both verbs is often used with emotions,except that only rough difference is  the verb subdue is applied to physical one-to-one confrontations like robber whereas the verb quell is applied to more  collective confrontations like riot

Comment: @Mrt - that's how the words are _generally_ used. But English is a flexible language, and you shouldn't be surprised if you see creative writers stretching beyond those boundaries.